# How can multiple unique in partition tabale?

Tags: sql, postgresql, partition

I have a SQL table like below.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
    id serial,
    user_id int,
    order_no character varying(50),
    date_time timestamp,
    primary key (id, user_id, date_time),
    unique(user_id, order_no)
) PARTITION BY RANGE (date_time);
```

I have a table. I need to unique `order_no` column with `user_id` column. there is no any problem.

But I have to unique `data_time` column because of I use partition. but `date_time` column has to be separated with `user_id` and `order_no`.

By the way I don't want like this `unique (user_id, order_no, data_time)`

How can I unique `date_time` in this table ?

Comment: This should be enough `date_time timestamp default now() unique`. BTW where does `tarih` come from in the primary key?

Comment: it was wrong. I fixed my mistake. sorry

Comment: Having  unique constraint on a column with default value `now()` may not be a good idea. You can not insert more than one row in a single transaction.

Comment: if I want, how can I add this @Stefanov.sm

Comment: This is wrong in several ways. IS REALLY COMMON having datetime not unique. Maybe with a mix key, but not only a field datetime.

Comment: Just add `unique` after `now()` in your DDL but - as @LeandroBardelli says - think twice before doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to create a unique index or constraint that guarantees that `order_no` or `user_id` are unique. That is one of the drawbacks of partitioning.

You could create unique constraints on the partitions. While that doesn't guarantee global uniqueness, it goes a long way.